# Remove lines with the character from the file

Tags: linux, shell

I have out put like this

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Sample
>

'< Jan 21 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Known Errors
>
```

So i need to remove all > special character from the file. Only the line where one special character > is present needs to be removed. 
I would like to have below out put

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Sample
'< Jan 21 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Known Errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sed

```
sed '/^>$/d' myfile
```

If the output if good for you, you can use the `-i` flag to override your file:

```
sed -i '/^>$/d' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -fvx '>' <myfile >myfile_with_offending_lines_removed
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13196081)

Comment: I think it does provide an answer. If the OP runs this command, he gets the output in the requested format. What am I missing?